# Git repo size after rewriting history on branch

Tags: git

I have a branch which is getting way too big due people in the past added some SQL dumps. It is 800M and after cleaning it up only 90M is left. However i have the use case where i have to repos:

Repo A
Repo B (which is a fork from Repo A).

What will happen when i cleanup the history of Repo A to remove that content, and then merge A in to B. Will B then be affected since technically the history is suddenly different?

Or what is the best way to handle this since the repo is getting way too big in this case and it is a non ending story of course.

What i did myself is a test and in that case the file size of B stayed the same like it was. This means that the history was changed on A but clearly not merge to B in that case? Executed it with below:

`git merge remotea/develop` into develop op remote b

Thanks for the feedback. Tips are welcome

Comment: It's not entirely clear what two repos you are talking about and what their relation is. Also, is it the size of the repository as a whole or the size of the files outside of `.git` that you are concerned about? Anyhow, when rewriting history, you are creating new commits that only seem to replace the old ones. A certain number of commits is still retained even though they can't be reached directly. Using e.g. `git gc` you can remove at least some of them.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is rewritten by https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ which is using `git filter branch`. The relations about the repos is mentioned. B is a fork from A on which they are technically somehow the same.  The concern is about the overall repo size as in `git count-objects -vH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge does not remove history.  Specifically:

You start with

```
C -- D -- E -- F <--(develop)
```

in both A and B.  You do some cleanup in repo A.  You didn't specify what you did, but suppose you end up with something like

```
C -- E' -- F' <--(develop)
```

in A.  (I'm supposing that `C` was unchanged, because otherwise your merge attempt would've complained and you'd have had to use the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option.)

Then in `B`, let's say you just run `git fetch`.  You'll have

```
C -- D -- E -- F <--(develop)
 \
  E' -- F' <--(remotea/develop)
```

Now if you merge, I'd think you get a lot of conflicts; but one way or other, you sort it out.  Well that means you have

```
C -- D -- E -- F -- M<--(develop)
 \                 /
  E' ----------- F' <--(remotea/develop)
```

and you see that you only add new history, so of course the repo doesn't shrink.

And if it were that simple, I guess the easy thing to do would be to re-create B by forking again.  But the fact that you have a fork suggests that some changes might live only in B.  Perhaps you really have

```
C -- D -- E -- X -- Y -- Z <--(develop)
 \
  E' -- F' <--(remotea/develop)
```

where `B` has not yet received `F` (or `F'`) but it has its own changes `X`..`Z`.

In that case cleaning up repo B is much harder, because the changes in repo B have to at some point be rebased into the revised history.

For example, you might try something like

```
git rebase --onto remotea/develop develop~2 develop
```

to get

```
C -- D -- E -- X -- Y -- Z
 \
  E' -- F' <--(remotea/develop)
          \
           X` -- Y` -- Z` <--(develop)
```

(or you could say `--onto remotea/develop^` and then merge if you want to preserve something more like the original commit topology).  But note that the original history still exists (albeit unreachably) for the time being.  It would have to eventually get `gc`'d, or you would have to do additional steps to force the clean-up sooner.  (Since you cleaned up repo A, I assume you have a sense of how that works.)

Still this is an oversimplification, as you may have a more complex history with repo B changes mixed in between updates from repo A.

```
  x -- x -- M -- x -- x -- M -- x -- x <--(develop)
 /         /              /         
C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H 
 \
  E' -- F' -- G' -- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origina/develop)
```

Here, the last time repo b took an update from repo a, `origina/develop` was at `H` which was merged in.  But now post-rewrite `origina/develop` has the new history.

What you have here, as the kids say, is a hot mess.  The current `develop` reaches "bad"/large commits by multiple paths, and the merge base with the remote is all the way back at `C`.  You could do a series of merges and rebases.  Each merge and each rebase could generate conflicts, and in particular if any of the original merges (when you were updating b from a) conflicted you'll have to redo those resolutions.

```
git checkout develop~6
git checkout -b temp
git merge origina/develop~5
```

yields

```
C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H 
|\         \              \
| x -- x -- M -- x -- x -- M -- x -- x <--(develop)
 \      \   
  E' --- M <--(temp)
   \
    F' -- G' -- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origina/develop)
```

THen

```
git checkout develop~3
git checkout -b temp2
git rebase --onto temp temp2~2
git branch -d temp
git merge origina/develop~2
```

yields

```
C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H 
|\         \              \
| x -- x -- M -- x -- x -- M -- x -- x <--(develop)
 \      \   
  E' --- M -- x' -- x' -- M <--(temp2)
   \                     /
    F' ------ G' ----- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origina/develop)
```

And finally

```
git rebase --onto temp2 develop~2 develop
git branch -d temp2
```

gives you

```
C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H 
|\         \              \
| x -- x -- M -- x -- x -- M -- x -- x
 \      \   
  E' --- M -- x' -- x' -- M -- x` -- x` <--(develop)
   \                     /
    F' ------ G' ----- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origina/develop)
```

As always the original history is still hanging around, but once you get it gc'd this becomes

```
C ------ E' -- F' -- G' -- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origin/develop)
 \         \                \
  x -- x -- M -- x' -- x' -- M -- x' -- x' <--(develop)
```

But even though I've mostly glossed over the conflict resolution complexity, you can see that this is a lot of work.

An alternative is to clean up the b repo independently, but that gives you something like

```
  x -- x -- M' -- x' -- x' -- M' -- x' -- x' <--(develop)
 /         /                 /         
C ------ E" -- F" -- G" -- H"
 \
  E' -- F' -- G' -- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origina/develop)
```

So then you have to explain to git that everything from `E'` through `H'` is already accounted for in `develop`, so you could maybe do something like

```
git checkout develop
git merge -s ours origin/develop~2
```

to get

```
  x -- x -- M' -- x' -- x' -- M' - x' - x' - m <--(develop)
 /         /                 /              /
C ------ E" -- F" -- G" -- H"              /
 \                                        /
  E' --------- F' --------- G' -------- H' -- I' -- J' <--(origina/develop)
```

Note that the lowercase-`m` is a *very* "non-default" merge result - it just keeps the content (`TREE`) that was already on `master`.  Because it surely would've conflicted using the default merge strategy, that's not the worst thing.

Anyway, the history is more weird this way, but it's a lot simpler.  Except it is predicated on doing the whole clean-up exercise twice (once in repo A, and separately in repo B).

The moral of the story is, the best way out of this situation is not to get into this situation.

Comment: Lol. What an answer for the best tldr at the end.